# Why is it not recommended to retrieve value from Scala's Future?

Tags: scala, future

I started working on Scala very recently and came across its feature called Future. I had posted a question for help with my code and some help from it.

In that conversation, I was told that it is not recommended to retrieve the value from a Future.

I understand that it is a parallel process when executed but if the value of a Future is not recommended to be retrieved, how/when do I access the result of it ? If the purpose of Future is to run a thread/process independent of main thread, why is it that it is not recommended to access it ? Will the Future automatically assign its output to its caller ? If so, how would we know when to access it ?

I wrote the below code to return a Future with a `Map[String, String]`.

```
def getBounds(incLogIdMap:scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]): Future[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]] = Future {
  var boundsMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
  incLogIdMap.keys.foreach(table => if(!incLogIdMap(table).contains("INVALID")) {
    val minMax    = s"select max(cast(to_char(update_tms,'yyyyddmmhhmmss') as bigint)) maxTms, min(cast(to_char(update_tms,'yyyyddmmhhmmss') as bigint)) minTms from queue.${table} where key_ids in (${incLogIdMap(table)})"
    val boundsDF  = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", commonParams.getGpConUrl()).option("dbtable", s"(${minMax}) as ctids")
      .option("user", commonParams.getGpUserName()).option("password", commonParams.getGpPwd()).load()
    val maxTms = boundsDF.select("minTms").head.getLong(0).toString + "," + boundsDF.select("maxTms").head.getLong(0).toString
    boundsMap += (table -> maxTms)
  }
  )
  boundsMap
}
```

If I have to use the value which is returned from the method getBounds, can I access it in the below way ?

```
val tmsobj = new MinMaxVals(spark, commonParams)
  tmsobj.getBounds(incLogIds) onComplete ({ 
  case Success(Map) => val boundsMap = tmsobj.getBounds(incLogIds) 
  case Failure(value) => println("Future failed..") 
})
```

Could anyone care to clear my doubts ?

Comment: `boundsMap` is both a `var` _and_ a mutable collection? That is needlessly redundant.

Comment: @jwh, So how can I frame the case of "Success". Because it says "Pattern type is incompatible with the expected type, found: mutable.map.type, required mutable.Map{String,String]"

Comment: You've missed the point of my comment. See my posted answer.

Answer (score 4):

As the others have pointed out, *waiting* to retrieve a value from a `Future` defeats the whole point of launching the `Future` in the first place.

But `onComplete()` doesn't cause the rest of your code to wait, it just attaches extra instructions to be carried out as part of the `Future` thread while the rest of your code goes on its merry way.

So what's wrong with your proposed code to access the result of `getBounds()`? Let's walk through it.

```
tmsobj.getBounds(incLogIds) onComplete { //launch Future, when it completes ...
  case Success(m) => //if Success then store the result Map in local variable "m"
    val boundsMap = tmsobj.getBounds(incLogIds) //launch a new and different Future
    //boundsMap is a local variable, it disappears after this code block

  case Failure(value) => //if Failure then store error in local variable "value"
    println("Future failed..") //send some info to STDOUT 
}//end of code block
```

You'll note that I changed `Success(Map)` to `Success(m)` because `Map` is a type (it's a companion object) and can't be used to match the result of your `Future`.

In conclusion: `onComplete()` doesn't cause your code to wait on the `Future`, which is good, but it is somewhat limited because it returns `Unit`, i.e. it has no return value with which it can communicate the result of the `Future`.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; `Futures` are not meant to manage shared state but they are good for composing asynchronous pieces of code. You can use `map`, `flatMap` and many other operations to combine `Futures`.

The computation that the `Future` represents will be executed using the given `ExecutionContext` (usually given implicitly), which will usually be on a thread-pool, so you are right to assume that the `Future` computation happens in parallel. Because of this concurrency, it is generally not advised to mutate state that is shared from inside the body of the `Future`, for example:

```
 var i: Int = 0
 val f: Future[Unit] = Future { 
     // Some computation
     i = 42
 }
```

Because you then run the risk of also accessing/modifying `i` in another thread (maybe the "main" one). In this kind of concurrent access situation, `Futures` would probably not be the right concurrency model, and you could imagine using monitors or message-passing instead.

Another possibility that is tempting but also discouraged is to block the main thread until the result becomes available:

```
val f: Future[Init] = Future { 42 }
val i: Int = Await.result(f)
```

The reason this is bad is that you will completely block the main thread, annealing the benefits of having concurrent execution in the first place. If you do this too much, you might also run in trouble because of a large number of threads that are blocked and hogging resources.

How do you then know when to access the result? You don't and it's actually the reason why you should try to compose `Futures` as much as possible, and only subscribe to their `onComplete` method at the very edge of your application. It's typical for most of your methods to take and return `Futures`, and only subscribe to them in very specific places.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to **wait** for a `Future` using `Await.result` because this blocks the execution of the current thread until some unknown point in the future, possibly forever.

It is perfectly OK to **process the value** of a `Future` by passing a processing function to a call such as `map` on the `Future`. This will call your function when the future is complete. The result of `map` is another `Future`, which can, in turn, be processed using `map`, `onComplete` or other methods.